# Powershell - Missing attribute error when assign file names to a variable with a for each loop

Tags: shell, powershell, variables, foreach, hashtable

I am trying to loop through a folder, get the filename of each file in the folder, than assign that filename to a variable. I would then use that variable in a hash table later on. This is where I am having the issue and keep receiving this error:

```
At C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR.ps1:19 char:16
+ Files.Add(fName, Counter)
+                ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
```

Here is the code:

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r' # Enter the root path you          want to monitor. 
$Failedfolder = 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r'
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 
$Files = @{}
$Counter = 1


# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if         required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property     @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,     LastWrite'} 

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 

ForEach ($file in folder) { 

$fName = file.Name

if (Files.ContainsKey(fName) = false)
{

Files.Add(fName, Counter)

}

if ((Files.ContainsKey(fName) = true) -and (Files.Item(fName) -lt 3))
{
Move-Item C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r\*.txt     C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test -force
Files.Set_Item(fName, Counter++)

}
ElseIf ((Files.ContainsKey(fName) = true) -and (Files.Item(fName) == 3))
{
Files.Remove(fName)
Move-Item C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r\*.txt Failedfolder -force
}

}

}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `$` before the variables. 
So replace all `fName` with `$fName`. You also have to rename  `file.Name` to `$file.Name`. You also miss a `$` on `Counter` in `Files.Add($fName, Counter)` and you have to write `$false` instead of `false`....

This should be the fixed version:

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r' # Enter the root path you          want to monitor. 
$Failedfolder = 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r'
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 
$Files = @{}
$Counter = 1


# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if         required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property     @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,     LastWrite'} 

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 

    ForEach ($file in $folder) 
    { 
        $fName = $file.Name

        if (-not $Files.ContainsKey($fName))
        {
            $Files.Add($fName, $Counter)
        }

        if (($Files.ContainsKey($fName)) -and ($Files.Item($fName) -lt 3))
        {
            Move-Item 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r\*.txt'  'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test' -force
            $Files.Set_Item($fName, $Counter++)

        }
        ElseIf (($Files.ContainsKey($fName)) -and ($Files.Item($fName) -eq 3))
        {
            $Files.Remove($fName)
            Move-Item 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r\*.txt' $Failedfolder -force
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I now get this error: Missing expression after ','

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as jisaak said, you had missed the variables with the expressions to it.

so replacing all the declarations with variables might fix the problem.

Also, one more thing, when you try to create any powershell script next time, try using **PSDebug cmdlet** to debug your scripts. It comes very handy. I find it very useful.

Just add the below code before running your script, or at the top of your script.

**Set-PSDebug -Trace 1**